# Ordenar tabela por um atributo que não está na Query SQL

Tags: php, sql

Eu tenho a seguinte query no meu código PHP:

```sql
SELECT id, totaldias, totalferiados FROM dias WHERE MONTH(data) = '$mes' ORDER BY totaldias
```

Até aí, funciona beleza. Mas eu implementei no sistema uma porcentagem que funciona da seguinte forma: Em uma outra query eu pego a data de entrada da pessoa na empresa, e conto quantos dias ela trabalhou desde que entrou, e tiro a porcentagem de quantos dias ela ficou de plantão e jogo na tabela. Mas como ordenar de quem tirou mais plantão para o que tirou menos? Mas o calculo é feito fora da query, como faço para conseguir ordenar?

Comment: Faça esse calculo dentro da sua query.

Comment: "Joga na tabela"? Se o dado está na tabela, é só ordenar por ele.

Comment: Na tabela que me referi foi a tabela do php. Perdão. Irei tentar fazer o cálculo dentro da própria query.

Comment: Se você calcula a % com PHP, use-o para ordenar. Coloque o codigo que você está usando

Comment: Sem ver o resto do seu código fica difícil ajudar, mas você poderia fazer tudo como uma única query, inclusive o calculo da porcentagem e usar um `ORDER BY` para ordenar. Poste a outra query e o calculo da porcentagem para poder te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Mais tarde vou postar, é que ficou no trabalho. Mas postarei mais tare.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: O projeto que eu estava trabalhando isso foi cancelado e não testei mais a solução.